# Install Commerce_Paypal Error

Tags: commerce

I have a brand new site that I created today.  When I run composer require 'drupal/commerce_paypal:^1.0@RC' I get this.  What do I need to do to get this resolved?  Shouldn't this just work?  I installed Drupal and Commerce using the command in the docs.   composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev

```
Problem 1
- drupal/commerce_paypal[1.0.0-rc1, ..., 1.0.0-rc6] require sainsburys/guzzle-oauth2-plugin ^3.0 -> satisfiable by sainsburys/guzzle-oauth2-plugin[v3.0.0, ..., v3.0.6].
- sainsburys/guzzle-oauth2-plugin[v3.0.0, ..., v3.0.2] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 7.4.5 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- sainsburys/guzzle-oauth2-plugin[v3.0.3, ..., v3.0.6] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 7.4.5 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- Root composer.json requires drupal/commerce_paypal ^1.0@RC -> satisfiable by drupal/commerce_paypal[1.0.0-rc1, ..., 1.0.0-rc6].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the output reads, there is a locked version of Guzzle prevents upgrading. Add the `-W` switch as directed.

Comment: Why would a new install have a locked version of anything?  Is that locked for a reason?

Comment: A lock file is created for every Composer build. That’s not a Drupal thing. That said, core-recommended could be in play here if -W does not work.